# LNK2001 static symbol unresolved, even though it is

Tags: c++, dllexport, unresolved-external

I know there are many solutions on unresolved static symbols here but I can't really find a solution to this problem.
I'm building a simple game framework as a DLL and I'm linking it with another project in my solution. When Actually it's the project I use for testing which is giving the error above not the framework itself. The code seems correct to me, I'm declaring it as a private parameter in the header file and declaring it before anything in the .cpp file.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 if it can help somehow.

Input.h file:

```
class DLLEXPORT Manager{
public:
    Manager();
};

class DLLEXPORT Input{
public:
    static void Foo();
public:
    friend class Manager;
    static Manager* m_manager;
};
```

Input.cpp file

```
#include "Manager.h"

Manager* Input::m_manager = 0;

Manager::Manager(){
    Input::m_manager = this;
}
```

PS: Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: so, does your test project link against the created `lib` file or your engine's project?

Comment: You need to declare things you export as dllexport, and things you import as dllimport. Are you doing this?

Comment: @n.m. I can't believe it was really that simple. All fixed now, thank you!